# How do I upload a screenshot in google projects?

Tags: google-code

I recently created a project (open source) on Google projects hosting.  I want to upload a screenshot, but I am not able to do it.  Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to host the image on a different server and reference it by simply writing the URL such as http://code.google.com/images/code_sm.png in the admin text area.

Comment: I don't want to host image on a different server, I don't have web space. Any other way ?

Comment: Yes add your image to a image hoster such as imageshack.us

Answer (score 0):

You can put the images in source repository and reference them from there. Simply upload it, browse through the directory and try to view for example the .png file. It will say 'This file is not plain text'. Look out for the link 'View raw file' on this page. Click on the link and you have the URL you need for the wiki. Worked for me with git, dont know about other vcs.